# I can't see the error in my xml sitemap

Tags: xml, validation, sitemap

I have made a sitemap that I basically print out from the DB.

I get an error on google sitemap validation, but I really can't see why. Hope someone can help.

error from validation:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------

Schema validator crashed
The maintainers of XSV will be notified, you don't need to send mail about this unless you have extra information to provide. If there are Schema errors reported below, try correcting them and re-running the validation.

    Length: 76774 bytes 
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5)
The target was not assessed
Low-level XML well-formedness and/or validity processing output


Error: Expected name, but got `<space>` for entity
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you have a literal `&` in the `<loc>` for Tropicana Golf & Country Resort. You should replace it with `&amp;`.

**This:**

```
<url><loc>http://website/ad/541/Linked%20House%20For%20Rent%20in%20Tropicana Golf & Country Resort,%20Tropicana</loc></url>
```

**Should be:**

```
<url><loc>http://website/ad/541/Linked%20House%20For%20Rent%20in%20Tropicana Golf &amp; Country Resort,%20Tropicana</loc></url>
```

Comment: Thanks :) How did you find it?

Comment: Opened it up in oXygen (http://www.oxygenxml.com/) and it took me right too it. Really any XML editor that shows well-formedness errors would point it out. The error message you got isn't very helpful, but generally any time you see an "unnamed entity" error, it's an ampersand issue. This is because ampersands start entity references.